# Link to a paper

Tags: reference-request, philosophy

I remember seeing, in one of the comments to one of the top-voted questions here, or on MO, a link to a paper.

It contained, in addition to other things, a part about the dangers of doing mathematics. The gist of it was that once in a while, the giants came around (Gauss etc) and gave you a few awe-inspiring gems, and then the rest of the mathematicians just 'filled up the gaps'.

I cannot, however, find it now. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking of [The Emotional Perils of Mathematics](https://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/Articles/Emotional-Perils.pdf) by Donald Weidman.

Comment: Exactly!!! This is it!